# How can I check if a character belongs to regular expression or not?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a function that tells if a character belongs to regular expression or not.

Following is my regular expression `var re=/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;`
Now if I have a character from string then i want to check whether that character belongs to regular expression or not.

Comment: Regular expressions describe strings of characters, so the condition "the character belongs to a regular expression" is not known to me. Could you give some examples of what you would consider included and not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the isMatch function.

```
YourRegex.IsMatch(yourCharachter);
```

Answer (score 1):

This site can help you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx
Regular expression methods are explained there.

code from link:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] partNumbers= { "1298-673-4192", "A08Z-931-468A", 
                              "_A90-123-129X", "12345-KKA-1230", 
                              "0919-2893-1256" };
      Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9](-\d{3}){2}[A-Za-z0-9]$");
      foreach (string partNumber in partNumbers)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a valid part number.", 
                           partNumber, 
                           rgx.IsMatch(partNumber) ? "is" : "is not");
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       1298-673-4192 is a valid part number. 
//       A08Z-931-468A is a valid part number. 
//       _A90-123-129X is not a valid part number. 
//       12345-KKA-1230 is not a valid part number. 
//       0919-2893-1256 is not a valid part number.
```